# yandex map + fullscreen

Tags: html, yandex-maps-api

Коллеги, вопрос про кнопку fullscreenControl. У меня эта кнопка никак не отрабатывает. Что делаю не так? У меня цель - карту отображаемую в iframe отобразить в полный экран. Сейчас ничего не происходит.

```
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1/yandex-map/" width="100%" height="500px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

...

```
var fullscreenControl = new ymaps.control.Button({
    data: {
        iconType: 'expand', title: "Развернуть/свернуть карту"
    },
    options: {
        selectOnClick: false,
        float: "right"
    }
});
fullscreenControl.events.add("press" ,function (){
    if (!fullscreenControl.isSelected())
        myMap.container.enterFullscreen();
    else
        myMap.container.exitFullscreen();
});
myMap.container.events.add("fullscreenenter" ,function() {
    fullscreenControl.data.set({iconType:"collapse"});
    fullscreenControl.select();
    console.log('fullscreenenter');
});
myMap.container.events.add("fullscreenexit" ,function() {
    fullscreenControl.data.set({iconType:"expand"});
    fullscreenControl.deselect();
    console.log('fullscreenexit');
});
myMap.controls.add(fullscreenControl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тег iframe - описывает контейнер, внутри которого отображается самостоятельная web-страница. Содержимое iframe не может выйти за его границы, соответственно кнопка fullScreen может действовать только в пределах размеров контейнера и не может развернуть карту на физический экран пользователя.

P.S. мы не советуем использовать 127.0.0.1 и другие ip адреса или фейковые домены, потому что есть риск попасть под бан за превышение лимита запросов с сайта - фактически вместе с вашими запросами посчитаются все запросы с сервисов, которые использует такой же фейковый хост.